# HTML apostophree mixing my content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, text

So, I don't really know how to even say, or explain my problem.

I have this code :

```
 string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString
 (
   File.ReadAllBytes (place + "/" + temname + ".html")
 );
 string editedText = text.Split
 (
   new string[] { "Edit4-->" }, 
   StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + "Edit4-->" + HTMLTEXT.Text + "</e4>" 
   + text.Split
   (
     new string[] { "Edit4-->" }, 
     StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split
     (
       new string[] { "</e4>" }, StringSplitOptions.None
     )[1];

     File.WriteAllText
     (
       place + "/" + temname + ".html", 
       editedText, Encoding.UTF8
     );
     break;
   )
 );
```

Which take a file, then take a text from textbox and split it together to save in a text, the file is writing in HTML, and the writing works perfect. The problem is, that when its save it to file i have this char: (uploading an img beacuse I can't copy it. I have no idea what is this char..)

[image]

I don't even know what it is and why it's here, but it mixing my html to a point where nothing works after it's there. When Idelete it all works fine, but whenever I use my code to write into the file, the char is back.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF8 encoded in the first place? What happens if you use File.ReadAllText() instead?

Comment: @Darek you should post your comment as the answer.

Comment: As you wish, @wdosanjos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspecting the file might not be UTF8 encoded ... use `File.ReadAllText()` instead.